C# to C interop and memory allocation
In C I have the following functions
uint8_t* allocateMem() {
    return malloc(4096);
}

void freeMem(uint8_t* ptr) {
    free(ptr);
}

and in C# code
[DllImport(memDllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern IntPtr allocateMem();
[DllImport(memDllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void freeMem(IntPtr ptr);

and am using it as under
var mem = allocateMem();
var bytes = new byte[4096];
Marshal.Copy(mem, bytes, 0, 4096);
freeMem(mem); // is this ok?

My question is when I call freeMem again with the IntPtr, will the memory (4096 bytes) that was allocated in C be freed?
Is there a guarantee to that? Are there any chances of memory leak with this pattern?
Trying to call C functions from C#. I want to confirm if the pattern I have used in code is correct.

If allocation failed (mem == NULL) , Marshal.Copy(mem, bytes, 0, 4096); is a concern.

@chux good catch!... will make the necessary changes ...

Yes this is the correct way to do this.
See this post for reference Just what is an IntPtr exactly?
It would be best to wrap such uses of unmanaged resources in RAII pattern Implementing RAII in C#

are there any tools to verify that the memory actually got freed on the C side. I would like to confirm if that really happens.

Have verified this by assigning a large piece of memory and then calling free. The memory indeed gets freed.

I'm not seeing the point in the need to use DllImport and C? If you're using C# you could just use these functions in C#.
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
static IntPtr AllocateMem() => Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4096);
static void FreeMem(IntPtr mem) => Marshal.FreeHGlobal(mem);

This would help prevent the need for extra dependencies while providing better optimazation and memory management.

there are other functions that the C side does which was not highlighted in the code for simplicity...

Perhaps some of the functions can be ported to c#? Possibly run a few tests to determine performance.

I don't know the exact nature of this use case, but I have encounted in the past 3rd party closed source libraries that do a malloc somewhere in their internal code and expect you to call free when you're done with the buffer/object.
I don't think that's the best design but sometimes it's just what you have to work with.

@Algebra what would be a better design then? passing in a buffer from managed and asking unmanaged to fill it?

It the buffer is only needed for the duration of the function call, yes. You cannot, however, keep any pointer allocated in managed (C#) code in your unmanaged (C) code.  Pointers are only valid for the duration of the specific marshaled call.
